# Can you use the Assassin's Assassinate with grenades or thrown area of effect weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, area-of-effect, assassin

Can you use the Assassin's Assassinate with grenades or thrown area of effect weapons?

> Assassinate: Starting at 3rd level, you are at your deadliest when you get the drop on your enemies. You have advantage on attack rolls against any creature that hasn't taken a turn in the combat yet. In addition, any hit you score against a creature that is surprised is a critical hit.

Alchemist's Fire has a 5 foot radius AOE or a stick of dynamite or grenade via DMG has something similar. These would be considered  ranged weapons/attacks...right? Not counting sneak attack damage, would an Assassin tossing one of these in the suprise round still deal critical damage to those in the AOE.

Ex: Assassin tossing a "grenade" at group "X" in the suprise round and grenade does a 3d6 fire (or piercing if frag grenade) in a 5 foot radius, would all in the AOE get dealt 6d6 fire (or piercing if frag grenade)?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate, you should find your answer on either of those linked questions.

Comment: If there's anything that the two questions doesn't answer for you, do please edit to point that out. As a fellow non-native (not that it's specific to that), I'll recommend getting a spell checker. There's a few available as browser extensions, and mine sure is helpful to me :)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Gentle reminder to try be actively friendly. It's easy to accidentally be come off as more abrasive than intended (which is a known challenge with text only communication) :)